# MailChimp popup won't show unless you scroll the page

Tags: javascript, html, mailchimp

This is really strange; I created a MailChimp popup subscription form and added the code to my web page.  I then wrapped the code into a function and added a button that will call the function when clicked.  When testing, the form will appear **only after** I attempt to **scroll the page**.  It's bizarre.

This script is in the beginning of the page:

```
<head>
  <!-- MailChimp popup -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showMailingPopUp() {

      // Remove the MailChip popup cookie
      document.cookie = "MCPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
      document.cookie = "MCPopupSubscribed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";

      // display the popup
      window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {
        L.start({
          "baseUrl": "mc.us18.list-manage.com",
          "uuid": "27aee96806da352efced26038",
          "lid": "cf688d3a39",
          "uniqueMethods": true
        });
      });

    };
  </script>
</head>
```

And here is my button in the body:

```
<body>
  <button onclick="showMailingPopUp()" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
</body>
```